# Trying to Convert Text File to CSV using Python Pandas but having 'utf-8' codec problems

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, type-conversion

I get the error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5070: invalid continuation byte. Nothing exports.

my code in question

```
# importing pandas library
import pandas as pd
  
# reading the given csv file 
# and creating dataframe
account = pd.read_csv("Output Configured 3.txt",
                      delimiter = '/')
  
# store dataframe into csv file
account.to_csv('Output Configured 3.csv',
               index = None)
```

What do I need to do to have it actually implement?

Comment: Assuming the error is on the `read_csv` line (include tracebacks!) the file isn't encoded in UTF-8.  Pass `encoding=<whatever_it_really_is>`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen you're correct, looks like I needed encoding latin-1. Thank you

Comment: `latin1` will decode anything, just silently mess up characters if it isn’t *really* Latin-1 a.k.a. ISO-8859-1. There are a lot of almost-the-same encodings.  Make sure to check the result esp. if you have non-ASCII characters

Comment: @MarkTolonen I will take that into account.